# How can I obtain an analytic function from a set of points from an image?

Tags: plotting, algebraic-manipulation, coordinate

So I have this image:

[image]

and I want to extract some piecewise-function of this nonperiodic wave-train, that will later be expanded to a Fourier series.

**Step 1:**
I use the Coordinate tool to get the point set:

```
points = {{{209.31751662971172`, 300.5625`}, {204.74101995565408`, 
     262.53214285714284`}, {201.02261640798224`, 
     296.88214285714287`}, {197.0181818181818`, 
     358.2214285714286`}, {194.72993348115298`, 
     300.5625`}, {191.29756097560974`, 
     269.8928571428571`}, {188.7232815964523`, 
     320.19107142857143`}, {185.86297117516628`, 
     296.88214285714287`}, {183.00266075388024`, 
     250.26428571428573`}, {181.28647450110861`, 
     301.7892857142857`}, {177.8541019955654`, 
     347.18035714285713`}, {172.13348115299334`, 
     316.5107142857143`}, {169.2731707317073`, 
     225.7285714285714`}, {166.12682926829265`, 
     295.65535714285716`}, {162.4084257206208`, 
     396.2517857142857`}, {159.5481152993348`, 
     295.65535714285716`}, {156.68780487804875`, 
     176.65714285714284`}, {153.82749445676274`, 
     294.4285714285714`}, {149.8230598669623`, 
     407.29285714285714`}, {144.96053215077603`, 
     311.6035714285714`}, {145.53259423503323`, 
     305.46964285714284`}, {145.81862527716186`, 
     293.2017857142857`}, {144.67450110864743`, 
     180.33749999999998`}, {140.3840354767184`, 
     289.52142857142854`}, {135.80753880266073`, 
     655.1035714285715`}, {130.9450110864745`, 
     185.65357142857147`}, {126.36851441241683`, 
     378.2589285714286`}, {122.65011086474499`, 
     293.6107142857143`}, {116.64345898004433`, 
     336.5482142857143`}, {112.92505543237249`, 
     259.2607142857143`}, {110.35077605321507`, 
     297.29107142857146`}, {105.7742793791574`, 
     325.5071428571429`}, {102.62793791574279`, 
     296.06428571428575`}, {98.90953436807094`, 
     255.58035714285717`}, {96.62128603104212`, 
     289.9303571428572`}, {93.47494456762747`, 
     320.6`}, {91.18669623059866`, 
     286.25000000000006`}, {87.46829268292682`, 
     296.06428571428575`}, {84.32195121951219`, 
     259.2607142857143`}, {82.60576496674057`, 
     297.29107142857146`}, {78.88736141906872`, 
     340.22857142857146`}, {76.3130820399113`, 
     326.73392857142863`}, {73.73880266075386`, 
     286.25000000000006`}, {72.59467849223945`, 
     226.13750000000005`}, {69.44833702882482`, 
     245.76607142857148`}, {66.87405764966739`, 
     293.6107142857143`}, {65.15787139689577`, 
     330.41428571428577`}, {62.58359201773834`, 
     352.4964285714286`}, {61.43946784922393`, 
     315.6928571428572`}, {58.8651884700665`, 291.1571428571429`}}};
```

**Step 2:**
I prepare a piecewise function of the points, where the deepest through is aligned with $y=0$ and  the tallest wave is aligned at $x=0$  :

```
points2 = {#[[1]], #[[2]] - 176.65714285714284`} & /@ points;

Clear[t];
f[t_] = Piecewise[
   Partition[Sort[points2], 2, 
     1] /. {{a_?NumericQ, b_}, {c_, d_}} :> {b, a <= t < c}];

f1[t_] = f[(135.80753880266073` (t + Pi)/Pi)];
Plot[f1[t], {t, -Pi, Pi}]
```

But I get a blank plot, which is strange.

Usually I get a plot which is a step-wise function of the wave-train, that can be later transformed into a Fourier series using:

```
FD[t_] = FourierSeries[f1[t], t, 15]
```

I cannot see any error in the codes here. Why is the plot blank?

Are there better methods to get an analytic function for Fourier series expansion?

I add here a working example of another reading:

```
points = {{461.25`, 156.`}, {457.5`, 144.75`}, {447.75`, 
    158.25`}, {445.5`, 167.25`}, {440.25`, 161.25`}, {433.5`, 
    144.75`}, {429.`, 154.5`}, {425.25`, 159.`}, {418.5`, 
    157.5`}, {412.5`, 150.`}, {409.5`, 161.25`}, {405.75`, 
    166.5`}, {402.75`, 152.25`}, {396.75`, 146.25`}, {390.`, 
    173.25`}, {385.5`, 162.75`}, {381.`, 138.`}, {375.`, 
    156.75`}, {369.75`, 151.5`}, {363.`, 163.5`}, {359.25`, 
    150.75`}, {355.5`, 138.`}, {351.75`, 150.`}, {345.`, 
    174.`}, {339.`, 154.5`}, {336.75`, 128.25`}, {331.5`, 
    141.`}, {327.`, 164.25`}, {321.`, 180.`}, {318.`, 
    162.75`}, {309.`, 132.`}, {308.25`, 139.5`}, {303.`, 
    191.25`}, {300.75`, 261.`}, {295.5`, 184.5`}, {288.`, 
    134.25`}, {280.5`, 153.75`}, {275.25`, 167.25`}, {269.25`, 
    171.`}, {264.`, 150.75`}, {260.25`, 138.75`}, {258.`, 
    154.5`}, {253.5`, 168.`}, {245.25`, 153.75`}, {241.5`, 
    153.75`}, {232.5`, 144.`}, {230.25`, 153.`}, {224.25`, 
    169.5`}, {221.25`, 153.75`}, {212.25`, 147.`}, {206.25`, 
    161.25`}, {201.`, 167.25`}, {197.25`, 144.`}, {192.`, 
    153.`}, {180.`, 158.25`}, {174.`, 162.75`}};

points2 = {#[[1]], #[[2]] - 128} & /@ points;

Clear[t];
f[t_] = Piecewise[
   Partition[Sort[points2], 2, 
     1] /. {{a_?NumericQ, b_}, {c_, d_}} :> {b, a <= t < c}];


f1[t_] = f[(300.75` (t + Pi)/Pi)];
Plot[f1[t], {t, -Pi, Pi}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

this gives:

[image]

which then by:

```
FD[t_] = FourierSeries[f1[t], t, 15]
```

gives:

[image]

The upper example does not work however, still the procedures are exactly the same.

Comment: There is are  two  points `{1111.4627274071884, 337.8744638367107}, {1111.4627274071884, \
323.29877237095116}` with same `x-value`.

Comment: Instead of `Piecewise` you might use `ip=Interpolation[points,InterpolationOrder->1]`, which makes skaling easier I think

Comment: Yes `ip[x]` may be used like a biuld in function

Comment: This sounds like an X,Y problem within a bad idea. @Vangsnes please [edit] your question to explain what is your goal, and your starting data. Share the code that creates your error. All this looks like a bad idea, extracting data from a pixelated image to build an interpolating function so it can be Fourier transformed analytically... Why? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. What is *"the point extraction tool"*?  What kind of analytical function do you expect? Do you already have a model to fit? What is the core goal here? The coefficients of a Flourier series? How many coefficients do you expect to know ? Is it important *"Why is the plot blank?"* in that context? Any chance of getting better quality data?

Comment: See update to answer more of your questions

Comment: Look at `points2` in the example that does not work. Also, you should be using `SetDelayed`, not `Set`. `ClearAll[f, f1]` then `f[t_] := ...`, `f2[t_] := ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we scale the data:

```
ma = PositionLargest[points[[All, 2]]][[1]]
mi = PositionSmallest[points[[All, 2]]][[1]]
points2 = {#[[1]] - points[[ma, 1]], #[[2]] - points[[mi, 2]]} & /@ 
   points;
ListPlot[points2]
```

[image]

Then we define the first piecewise function:

```
f[t_?NumericQ] = 
  Piecewise[
   Partition[Sort[points2], 2, 
     1] /. {{a_?NumericQ, b_}, {c_, d_}} :> {b, a <= t < c}];
Plot[f[t], {t, Min[points2[[All, 1]]], Max[points2[[All, 1]]]}]
```

[image]

Finally we scale the x range:

```
f1[t_] = 
  f[(t + Pi) (Max[points2[[All, 1]]] - 
        Min[points2[[All, 1]]])/(2 Pi) + Min[points2[[All, 1]]] ];
Plot[f1[t], {t, -Pi, Pi}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

Now the Fourier transform works as expected.

Comment: which version do you use? I have Mathematica 13.0.1 and I get at your first command:  $RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of {-{{{99.4975,139.53},{99.4975,158.795},{97.2799,125.518},{93.7317,99.2472},{91.514,155.293},{89.2964,183.315},{86.1917,165.801},{83.5306,143.033},{82.6435,72.9759},{79.9824,100.999},<<28>>}}[[ma,1]]+{{99.4975,139.53},{99.4975,158.795},{97.2799,125.518},<<6>>,{79.9824,100.999},<<28>>}[1],-{{<<1>>}}[[mi,2]]+{<<1>>}[2]}.

ListPlot::lpn: points2 is not a list of numbers or pairs of numbers.

Comment: I forgot to convert the first command from text to code. It is fixed and should work now. I am using  version 13.2, but I do not think this is the issue.

Comment: You're right, it was a miscode in my sheet. Thanks for the correction